# Accessing SWF files in SharePoint document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

We are uploading SWF files in a document library in SharePoint Online.

When we try to download the files using complete URL like `https://org.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteCollection/Shared Documents/Folder/file.swf`, it gives message in browser `403 FORBIDDEN`.

Also, when we try to use "Copy Link" feature to copy the URL of the SWF file it gives URL as `https://org.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteCollection/_layouts/15/download.aspx?UniqueId=SomeUniqueID` rather than folder path.

I found some articles like [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7a922628-fa57-4b7c-ace6-35586cf9fc32/upload-swf-file-to-sharepoint-online?forum=onlineservicessharepoint) and [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/office-365/can-t-play-swf-files-from-onedrive-or-sharepoint/m-p/27004) which seem to suggest that we cannot upload SWF files in SharePoint Online. But I am not able to find any official article from MSDN regarding this.

How can I allow users to download files stored in SharePoint document library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recent improvements in SharePoint Online have removed the limitations on types of files that can be added. There are currently no known types of files that cannot be added.

The SWF file type in SharePoint document library won't work unless the site allows you to run custom script. By default, custom script is blocked on user-created sites that have Office 365 groups.

Go to SharePoint Online Admin center -> Settings -> Custom Script, select “Allow users to run custom script on self-created sites.” It can take up to 24 hours for the change to take effect. To allow custom script immediately, run the following script:

```
connect-sposervice https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com

Set-SPOsite https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/TeamSite1 -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0
```

Reference:[Types of files that cannot be added to a list or library](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/types-of-files-that-cannot-be-added-to-a-list-or-library-30be234d-e551-4c2a-8de8-f8546ffbf5b3)